# Double foreign key dilemma with Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I have an ASP.NET MVC project and am using the Identity framework for my users.

The project involves `Customers` and `Agents`, which are just different roles of regular identity users.

A table called `Orders` belongs to both a `Customer` and also an `Agent`.

```
public class Order
{
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int AgentID { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ApplicationUser> Agent { get; set; }
}
```

But this model definition won't work and produces incorrect SQL when using `add-migration`.

What is the best way to accomplish this with code first? Should I explicitly define foreign keys, or would it be better to create join tables to avoid the 2 foreign key reference to the `IdentityUser` table?

Comment: Is your identity database different from where the Order table is? I believe it is one to many relation ship with Applicationuser to Order so foreign key would be in Applicatoinuser. Post ApplicationUser model in your class!

Comment: Everything is in the same database.  I have not overridden anything in the ApplucationUser model - it is the default class from Identity.

Comment: That's the problem how Entity framework would know which end property to connect with which collection. Just try adding navigation property in ApplicationUser. and then run migration.

Comment: Well, I need to save the association between Orders, Customers, and Agents. Should I just save this in IDs and skip the foreign key associations?  That doesn't seem like a "clean" way to do it  but it might work.

Comment: Well, this is how relational databases work. If you wanted to create association between entities, you need to define foreign keys and add constraints to entities. I don't understand why you call that approach "not clean"!

Comment: I updated my question with more complete code - does this help explain what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with this class definition for Order:

```
public class Order
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Agent { get; set; }

}
```

Entity figured the rest out correctly with this.

Answer (score 0):

One Order can belong to only one Customer and one Agent, so no need of using Collection for Customer and Agent. Instead

```
 public class Order
{
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Customer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Agent")]
    public int AgentID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser Agent { get; set; }
}
```